# anchor not sizing buttons properly and text disappearing how to fix it?

Tags: c#

in the video below you can see how my buttons behave when i try to resize the window after anchoring them. My application does not have an exist button for some reason either, could not find a solution online and have no clue on how to fix it for the time being. Sorry for potato quality....

https://youtu.be/6WY_19Qdy4c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know that sometimes anchor cannot fix of what will you want to achieve?

Instead of anchoring you can use `tableLayoutPanel`?

The only properties of `tableLayoutPanel` is `Dock = Fill`;

After that you can now add columns and rows in the table and button inside the cell, it will automatically resize your button.

1. Add a tableLayoutPanel set `Dock` to `Fill`
2. Click tableLayoutPanel

   - Edit Rows and Columns (Add Column or Rows Change Absolute to Percent it should be 50%)
   - Press OK

If you want to span Rows and Columns click the control inside the Cell and find `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` in the properties

Comment: oh did not realize they were a thing before this. Thank you for the clarification.